# is there a faster way to compare two raws in a two tensors than for loop?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

im new to pytorch and i would like to check for each element in the `tensor1` if it is part of the same row in the `tensor2` for example if i have two tensor as follwoing:

```
a = torch.tensor([[0,5],[1,5], [4,5], [7,8]])
b = torch.tensor([[0,1],[2,3], [7,5], [-1,7]])
```

the output should be as following:

```
[ True, False]
[False, False]
[False, False]
[False, False]
[False, False]
[False,  True]
[False,  True]
[False, False]
```

i know that i can do it using a simple for loop but is there a way to do it faster in `pytorch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the `repeat_interleave` for both tensors and then `reshape` the first tensor, and then you compare it with the other tensor
like this

```
res = a.repeat_interleave(2, dim=1).reshape(-1, 2) == b.repeat_interleave(2, dim=0)
```

the output should be as follows

```
output
tensor([[ True, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False,  True],
        [False,  True],
        [False, False]])
```

the output is tensor. If you need it without `[]` you can use the `flatten` method